# Child ul not showing when parent ul set with overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

### HTML

```
 <div id="gadget">
 <span id="nav_up">UP</span>
    <ul>
       <li>LIST1
           <ul>
             <li>Child1.1</li>
             <li>Child1.2</li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li>LIST2
           <ul>
             <li>>Child2.1</li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li>LIST3
           <ul>
             <li>>Child3.1</li>
           </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
 <span id="nav_down">Down</span>
 </div>
```

### CSS

```
  #gadget{width:75px; height: 100%;}
  #gadget ul{height:450px; width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
  #gadget ul li ul{display:none;}
  #gadget ul li:hover ul{display:block;}
```

### JS

```
$('#nav_down').click(
    function () {
        $('#gadget ul').animate({scrollTop: '100px'}, 800);
    }
);

$('#nav_up').click(
    function () {
        $('#gadget ul').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 800);
    }
);
```

Here on click `<span>` up and down the gadget `<ul>` moves up and down according to the overflow.
But when overflow:hidden is applied the child `<ul>` is not showing. And when I remove it child `<ul>` shows but the `<span>` scroll dosenot work. How can i solve this?

Comment: Any chance we could get a jsfiddle.net? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EYrn6/1/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is all of your ULs are height:450px, would applying the height to only the top element solve the problems?

```
 #gadget > ul{height:450px; width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nested ul needs to be absolutely positioned and for proper scrolling grab the body element and apply the animate method http://jsfiddle.net/PJ3gp/

```
#gadget ul li ul{display:none;position:absolute;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add position:absolute to child elements